# c++ code showing bad_alloc error while using vectors

Tags: c++, string, vector, bad-alloc

the code shows std::bad_alloc error dont know what to do about it when remove the push_back it dissapears. please help on what to do. this happens only when I am entering a huge string s else it runs perfectly fine. is there another efficient way to find all the possible substring, arrange them lexicographicaly and then concatinate them back into one string????pls help
thnx in advance

```
#include <cmath>
#include <set>
#include <cstdio> 
#include <vector> 
#include <iostream> 
#include<string> 
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std; 

bool sortByString(string &t1, string &t2)
{
   return t1 < t2;
}

int main() {

   string s,sub,i,c,q; 

   int T;
   cin>>T;

   while(T--){

      cin >> s;

      int length = s.length();

      cin>>q;
      vector<string> ss;

      for (c = 0; c < length; c++)
      {
         for (i =length-c;i>=1; i--)
         {
            ss.push_back(s.substr(c,i));
         }
      }

      s="";

      set<string> se(ss.begin(),ss.end());
      ss.assign(se.begin(),se.end());

      vector<string>::iterator p;

      for( p=ss.begin();p!=ss.end();++p)
         s.append(*p);   

      cout<<s[q-1]<<endl;
   }

   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: How huge is the string that you are entering?

Comment: Sentences. Use them.

Comment: What compiler are you using? `i` is defined to be of type `string`. That is not right. It should be an integral type. Did the compiler not produce any errors or warnings? `c` also suffers from the same problem.

Comment: please post code that compiles.

Comment: 'i' is an integer made a mistake!!

Comment: the string is longer by nearly 400 characters more than what i can type here

Comment: Hello, note that `processing` tag is for processing.org Removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string of N characters, there are about N^2/2 substrings with something like N^3/6 total characters. For a huge input strings, this can be a lot.

Eventually you need to output them all, so the only way to reduce the memory footprint is to avoid storing all these substrings/characters at the same time.

One obvious optimisation would be to store just (start, end) index pairs instead of the substrings. When you need to compare or print substrings, you make them out of index pairs and the original string, do whatever, and discard them.

This will help you get rid of the cube, but that may not be enough for really huge strings.

Another observation that can help you is that out of substrings with the same origin, the shorter one is lexicograpgically smaller. You can use the fact to e.g. reduce the number of possibilities when generating the smallest yet-unused substring. I won't go into much detail here so as not to spoil the fun, but you can use an array where i-th element stores the length of the shortest substring starting at i that was not printed yet.

Comment: I understand why it doesnt work. But I dont understand the aleternate solution u are suggesting. please be elaborate !!

Comment: after finding all the substrings I need to sort them lexicographically.

Comment: I have outlined two different methods. One is about storing substrings economically. You still sort them as normal, just a representation is different. The other method generates them in sorted order to begin with. There is no detailed description of the second method, only a hint. You are supposed to work on it yourself.

Comment: ok now I get the second method you were talking about. but how do store two indexes. I dont know what data type to use for that. after saving them how do sort indexes ??

Comment: Try `std::pair<int,int>`. You can also create your own struct.

Comment: how do I sort strucures.

Comment: You have to learn how to use std::sort with custom comparators.